# Java Script Currency Format - Convert Code to Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, currency, number-formatting

Can anyone tell me how to modify this to work in Google Apps Script

```
       function formatCurrency(symbol, amount) {
               aDigits = amount.toFixed(2).split(".");
               aDigits[0] = aDigits[0].split("").reverse().join("")
                       .replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join("");
               return symbol + aDigits.join(".");
}
```

Would be great to have this working for currency formatting.

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me. I just ran it in the debugger here: https://docs.google.com/macros

```
function formatCurrency(symbol, amount) {
  var aDigits = amount.toFixed(2).split(".");
  aDigits[0] = aDigits[0].split("").reverse().join("")
    .replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join("");
  return symbol + aDigits.join(".");
}

function test() {
  var foo = formatCurrency('$', 3.5);
  debugger;
}
```

Paste it in, save it, change the "Select function" dropdown to "test" and run it.

---

I made an edit to declare the undeclared variable `aDigits`, but Google Apps Script didn't need the declaration to work. The `var` keyword should be there, though, otherwise `aDigits` is leaked into the global scope.